# NaN values emerging when concatenating multiple dataframes with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple dataframes with data for each quarter of the year. My goal is to concatenate all of them so I can sum values and have a vision for my entire year.

I managed to concatenate the four dataframes (that have the same column names and same rows names) into one. But I keep getting NaN at two columns, even though I have the data. It goes like this

df1:

```
   my_data        1st_quarter 
0  occurrence_1   2
1  occurrence_3   3
2  occurrence_2   0
```

df2:

```
   my_data        2nd_quarter 
0  occurrence_1   5
1  occurrence_3   10
2  occurrence_2   3
```

df3:

```
   my_data        3th_quarter 
0  occurrence_1   10
1  occurrence_3   2
2  occurrence_2   1
```

So I run this:

```
df_results = pd.concat(
    (df_results.set_index('my_data') for df_results in [df1, df2, df3]),
    axis=1, join='outer'
).reset_index()
```

What Is happening is this output:

```
   type           1st_quarter  2nd_quarter  3th_quarter
0  occurrence_1   2            NaN          10
1  occurrence_3   3            10           2
2  occurrence_2   0            3            1
3  occurrence_1   NaN          5            NaN
```

If I use `join='inner'`, the first row disappear. Note that the rows have the exact same name in all dataframes.

How can I solve the `NaN` problem? Or after doing `pd.concat` reorganize my DF to "fill" the `NaN` with the correct numbers?

Update: My original dataset (which I unfortunately can post publicly) has a inconsistency in the first row name. Any suggestions about how I can get around it? Can I rename a row? Or combine two rows after a concatenate the dataframes?

Comment: No repro. Seems like `occurrence_1` is not actually the same name in all dataframes. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp8JN.png

Comment: @BigBen the actual dataframe that I'm working is a little bit different with the rows names (I can't post it here). Maybe the problem is with encoding? I'll explore that. But, in any case, is there a way that I can rename a row in each df to ensure this won't happen? Or at least combine the row number 0 with row number 3?

Comment: Possibly, but it's a bit hard to say without knowing what the actual data is.

Comment: How I can rename a row in each df to ensure this won't happen? Or at least combine the row number 0 with row number 3?

Comment: maybe there is white space around `occurrence_1` in one of the DataFrames? Perhaps try `df1['type'].str.strip()` and `df2['type'].str.strip()` before concatenation.

Comment: Can you repeat the experiment with df_results.set_index('my_data') for df_results in [df1, df1, df1]?

Comment: @keramat If i go with the df_results.set_index('my_data') for df_results in [df1, df1, df1], it works perfect. Clearly my original dataset has a inconsistency in the first row name. Any suggestions about how I can get around it?

Comment: Why do not you just replace them?

Comment: Replace what, exactly? Sorry, but I didn't understand.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to get around this problem using [combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with loc:

```
df_results.loc[0] = df_results.loc[0].combine_first(df_results.loc[3])
```

So I got this:

```
   type           1st_quarter  2nd_quarter  3th_quarter
0  occurrence_1   2            5            10
1  occurrence_3   3            10           2
2  occurrence_2   0            3            1
3  occurrence_1   NaN          5            NaN
```

Then I dropped the last line:

```
df_results = df_results.drop([3])
```